# Skip initial scan for tailable cursor queries with awaitdata=true and storage engine wiredTiger

Tags: mongodb

I am using the mongodb `oplog.$main` collection in a single master instance for even streaming in my app. When my app starts, it queries the oplog collection with a tailable cursor waiting for new data, but mongo cpu spikes because this query scans the full oplog collection (which in my case is 25GB). From mongodb documentation:

- Because tailable cursors do not use indexes, the initial scan for the query may be expensive; but, after initially exhausting the cursor, subsequent retrievals of the newly added documents are inexpensive.

Is there any way to skip the initial scan of the query? I am only interested in new documents added to oplog.
I have tried with `{oplogReplay: true}` and the filter `{ts: {$gt: lastOplogTime}}`, but the mongo CPU still spikes. I am using mongo 3.0.3 with storage engine wiredTiger. Also, using `sort({$natural: -1})` does not work since I get this error from mongo:

- `invalid sort specified for tailable cursor: { $natural: -1 }`.

Looks like the `sort` error is due to be using `wiredTiger`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!